# How to create a new UIImageView with a different instance variable every time a timer is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

how are you guy's?

I want to make a new instance variable every time a timer is called for e.g.

```
        numberofObjects += 1;
    i = numberofObjects;

    UIImageView *Object[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randomx,0,36 ,36)];        
    UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
    [Object[i] setImage:imag];
    [self.view addSubview:Object[i]];
```

Is there a way to do this?

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Let me guess, you come from JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't too hard to do. I make the assumption that you are only going to have a maximum number of UIImageViews, as this can add a lot of overhead, and you may run into problems if it's allowed to continue forever. In the .h file,

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController {
  int numberAdded;
  NSTimer * timer;
  UIImageView * currentImageView;
  NSMutableArray * arrayOfImageViews;
}

- (void)addNewImageView;

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
#define MaxImageViews 20 // This is changeable!

@implementation viewController

- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  numberAdded = 0;
  arrayOfImageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(addNewImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)addNewImageView; {
  if(numberAdded >= MaxImageViews){
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    return;
  }
  int randomX = arc4random() % 320; // Gives value from 0 - 319.
  int randomY = arc4random() % 480; // Gives value from 0 - 479.
  UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, 36, 36)];
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
  [arrayOfImageViews addObject:imageView];
  [currentImageView release];
      currentImageView = imageView;
    }

- (void)dealloc; {
  [currentImageView release];
  [arrayOfImageViews release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This should keep track of all of the imageViews in the array `arrayOfImageViews`, and you can access the i-th imageView by calling `[arrayOfImageViews objectAtIndex:i]`. The `currentImageView` pointer keeps track of the latest UIImageView added. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your comment but I'm looking for a way to change to ponters name for e.g imageView1,imageView2.imageView3... so i can add it to a NSMutableArray and check the collision with another imageView. Do you got any ideas there?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "to change to ponters name for e.g imageView1,imageView2.imageView3...". Do you mean you want to keep track of each of the imageViews? If so, I will edit my above code.

Comment: ok for e.j I have a NSMutableArray that is being populated with the UIimageView that i create        every .5 sec with a pointer called imageView. so what I'm trying to do is to change the pointer to imageView1,imageView2.... when the timer is call. so it's like timer run imageView1 then the timer runs again and now its imageView2 end etc.

Answer (score 0):

Store the image views' pointers in an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/) object.

Comment: I'am but the problem is that i need to get a new pointer for that object so i can check collision. For e.g object1,object2,object3...

Comment: @Jean Pierre: Variable names and pointers are two different things. If you want to associate each image view with a name or other unique key, use an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: thanks but is there a way to do this I have a NSMutableArray that is being populated with the UIimageView that i create every .5 sec with a pointer called imageView. so what I'm trying to do is to change the pointer to imageView1,imageView2.... when the timer is call. so it's like timer run imageView1 then the timer runs again and now its imageView2 end etc.

Comment: @Jean Pierre: Again, that has nothing to do with pointers. You are talking about variable names. And no: You cannot change variable names at run time. What you need to do is keep a variable of type `NSUInteger` that holds an index into the array. (Note that array indexes in C and Cocoa start at 0, not 1.)

Comment: Declare an instance variable holding a pointer to an NSMutableArray object, and another holding an NSUInteger. Keep the index of the image view you're currently interested in in the NSUInteger variable, and use that index to retrieve the image view from the array.